# Excel to replace formulas with values

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook (1) with around 9 sheets that is pulling in and manipulating data from a second workbook (2).

After pulling in the data from workbook (2) I need to be able to replace the formulas in workbook (1) to the resulting values that the formulas have produced, from here I will then save the workbook (1) with the results.

Is there a macro that can do this for me?

Comment: Yes, just copy the range and use `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` An example would be `Range("A1:D10").Copy Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: @Omar. Many thanks Omar, however I need a script to copy all values over a number of worksheets, nit just a range. In addition I know very little about VB therefore need a full script.

Comment: Use a For loop to go through all worksheets, copy then paste special as values. There are plenty of code examples how to do these things.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On your new workbook some basic code such as:

```
Sub Value()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.UsedRange.Value = ws.UsedRange.Value
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This should work in most cases, but I'd use .Value2 rather than .Value. It's faster than doesn't have issues with any cell data types.

Answer (score 1):

While the OP is dated, I want to make note of a non-loop method that is useful. In certain scenarios, loops can really slow down the code execution. To replace formulas in a cell --without a loop-- try:

```
With Sheets("example").Range("A1:C1000")
   .value = .value
End With
```

You can revise the reference as necessary, but the execution is seamless, fast, and as a bonus - prevents range highlighting that cannot be cleared if you pursued the `.copy + .pastespecial xlPasteValues` approach.

Answer (score -1):

What seems to work for me is to use `concatenate()`

So, for example, the formula I have referencing a cell from another sheet is:

```
=arrayformula(iferror(index('To Be Processed'!X:X,small(if($A$1='To Be 
Processed'!$Y2,row('To Be Processed'!X:X)),row((2:2))),"")))
```

and if I change to the formula to:

```
=concatenate(arrayformula(iferror(index('To Be
Processed'!X:X,small(if($A$1='To Be Processed'!$Y2,row('To Be
Processed'!X:X)),row((2:2))),""))))
```

and it puts in the text value from the reference cell into my second sheet.

Which may or may not be helpful depending on how you populate your sheets--I'm not very good with VBA, though, which means I do more things manually :)